# What is the force exerted by a fluid on the corner of a right-angled tube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

It is to be considered that the water is entering and leaving at the same velocity v.

---

I have found a solution but cannot understand it as it is using a term dM/dt which I cannot understand in this scenario.

Comment: Have you studied calculus? Are you familiar with the definition that force is the time-derivative of momentum? $F=d(Mv)/dt$.

Comment: The post refers to a solution and says you cannot understand it, but you don't give the solution so we have no idea what you're talking about. Please post the solution so we can comment on it and explain why it makes sense, if indeed it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes called a right-angled **bend** in a pipe of uniform cross-sectional area.  If the entrance and exit of the pipe are aligned with the x direction and the y directions, respectively, fluid enters the bend with all its momentum in the x direction and leaves with all its momentum in the y direction.  So it experiences a rate of change of momentum in both directions.  To bring about this change in momentum, the pipe must exert a force on the fluid; and the fluid must exert an equal and opposite force on the pipe.  The dM/dt they are referring to could represent the rate of change of momentum of the fluid in the bend, or it could represent the the rate of mass entering or leaving.  If dM/dt represents the rate of mass entering or leaving, then the change in x momentum of the fluid is $-vdM/dt$ and the rate of change of y momentum of the fluid is +vdM/dt, where v is the fluid velocity in the pipe.  The rate of change of x momentum of the fluid in passing through the bend is equal to the force that the pipe exerts on the fluid in the x direction, and similarly for the y direction.  So the force that the fluid exerts on the bend has a component +vdM/dt in the x direction and a component -vdM/dt in the y direction.  What we're talking about here is often referred to as a Macroscopic Momentum Balance.